# Group & minimum relation property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

newbie in Neo4j, I'm look to get the user who will pass the minimum time for a task.

For the moment, I've this query.  It's working but I can't have the name of the user with the minimum time in the relation.  I've just the task and the time

```
MATCH (task:Task)<-[relation:can_do_it]-(user:User)
WITH task.title as taskTitle, MIN(relation.time) AS minimumTime
RETURN taskTitle, minimumTime
```

Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATED]

1.
To find the user who was the fastest at *any* task, you can sort the results by time and return just the first one:

```
MATCH (task:Task)<-[rel:can_do_it]-(user:User)
RETURN task.title as taskTitle, rel.time AS minimumTime, user.name as name
ORDER BY minimumTime
LIMIT 1
```

2.
To find the user who was the fastest at *each* task, you can sort the results by time, use [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to collect the (sorted) data for each task, and then return each task and the first element in each collection:

```
MATCH (task:Task)<-[rel:can_do_it]-(user:User)
WITH task, {time: rel.time, name: user.name} AS data
ORDER BY data.time
RETURN task.title AS taskTitle, COLLECT(data)[0] AS minData
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but with this way, I only get the most quick task  not all the differents tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to APOC procedures, the 3.5.0.5 fall release includes a new aggregation function `apoc.coll.minItems()` (as well as a `maxItems()` variation) that is meant to obtain the items associated with some min or max value.

Usage in this case would be:

```
MATCH (task:Task)<-[relation:can_do_it]-(user:User)
WITH task, apoc.agg.minItems(user, relation.time) AS minResult
RETURN task.title as taskTitle, minResult.items[0].name as name, minResult.value as minimumTime
```

The `minResult()` returned structure would look something like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Lemony Snicket",
    }
  ],
  "value": 15
}
```

The function will return all possible entries that have the same min (or max) value, but you can supply a third parameter to the function call that will limit it to a certain number of items (so `apoc.agg.minItems(user, relation.time, 1)` if you only needed one result, even if there are ties).

And just to note, the context of the aggregation, like for any aggregation function, is the non-aggregation variables. Since `task` is the non-aggregation variable, the minItems() aggregation will execute per distinct task.